# D3 Plus - Dynamically changing the position of data points in Scatter Plot

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I need to update the **X and Y coordinates** of a data point on `click event` and move it to new position on plot.

**Code**:

```
var sample_data = [
  {"value": 100, "weight": .45, "type": "alpha"},
  {"value": 70, "weight": .60, "type": "beta"},
  {"value": 40, "weight": 0.80, "type": "gamma"},
  {"value": 15, "weight": .32, "type": "delta"}
];

$(function(){
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
                            .container("#dv-container")
                            .data(sample_data)
                            .type("scatter")
                            .id("type")
                            .x("value")
                            .y("weight")
                            .height(400)
                            .width(600)
                            .draw();

  $("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
    //update the value of first data point
    sample_data[0].value = 50;
    sample_data[0].weight = 0.5;

    //this is where I need help to update the chart
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7L3wpwa/5/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do  `visualization.data(sample_data).draw();` for redrawing on button click:

```
 $("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
        //update the value of first data point
        sample_data[0].value = 50;
        sample_data[0].weight = 0.5;
        //redraw
        visualization.data(sample_data).draw();
    });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/nvLnntjq/)

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly. but this is just a demo and real data can be quite large. I'm a little concerned about the performance issue when re drawing the whole viz from scratch. isn't there any other way that I can individually change position of certain data points?

Comment: I don't think its possible using d3plus(Nothing in the available API doc), unless you go and hack the code.
You will need to redraw coz of two reasons:
1) scale may change.
2) If scale changes then the position of circles will also change.

Comment: yes, I have seen the docs and found nothing. thank you for your help though. I'll go with this solution for now.

Comment: Cyril is right, editing the coordinates of a data point directly from the visualization is not currently supported.